SwiftUI: Problems creating a confirmation view for deleting from a List
I have a view with a List. When an item is deleted from the list I want to show a sheet to confirm that the user really wants to delete the item.
In the view with the List, when the user deletes a row, I store the deleted offsets in a State variable. I then show the DeleteConfirmationView
@State private var deleteOffsets: IndexSet?
I pass deleteOffsets to the DeleteConfirmationView so that the data can be deleted if the user confirms.
Code example summary:
var body: some View {
 Group {
   List {
      ForEach(...) {
        //stuff
      }
      .onDelete(perform: preDelete)
   }
  }
  .sheet(isPresented: $showDeleteConfirmation) {
    if let delOffsets = deleteOffsets {
       DeleteConfirmationView(delValue: fakeData[delOffsets.first!].aValue, delIndex: delOffsets.first) {
               realDelete(at: delOffsets)
       }
    }
    else {
       Text("Error")
    }
   }

}

func preDelete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    deleteOffsets = offsets
    showDeleteConfirmation = true
}

func realDelete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    offsets.forEach { index in
        let aData = fakeData[index]
        context.delete(aData)
    }
}



However, deleteOffsets is nil when the code inside .sheet is entered. I set debugger breakpoints and ensured that preDelete is called before reaching the code inside .sheet. But still deleteOffsets is nil!!
What am I doing incorrectly? Can anyone help me.
This repository has the code.

Use .sheet(item: ...) instead, it is designed for that specific purpose. See the docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:). Note, you post maybe marked as duplicate linking to some old hacks. Use .sheet(item: ...) to "Presents a sheet using the given item as a data source for the sheet’s content."

I believe this is a bug in SwiftUI. In the repository see the "Note" comment in ContentView.swift
The issue can be made to go away by just reffering to a variable within the view

I think this is normal behaviour, the reason is because the .sheet(isPresented: ...) does not capture
the surounding valiables. You can do that yourself if you doubd that .sheet(item:..) does
not work. For example, using .sheet(isPresented: $showDeleteConfirmation) { [fakeData] in ...
to capture fakeData.
